# Trying to split tunnel with my VPN but I can't find 'executable' files?

Tags: vpn

I want to split tunnel with my VPN (PIA) so things like Deluge run ONLY through the VPN, and things like Plex do not. I also want Deluge to boot on start up.

How do I find the executable files to add to the split tunnel?

How do I make a program boot on start up? (I understand how to do this for programs like browsers (add it to the Start Applications), but again, I can't find the executable for Deluge, and just typing "Deluge" doesn't work).

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/deluge/filelist (*nix executables are mostly all lower case i.e. `deluge` not `Deluge`)

Comment: This was so helpful, @steeldriver - thank you!